# SVG arc is not following the ellipse

Tags: svg, path, automatic-ref-counting, ellipse

I want to draw a part of the ellipse with the arc path. But it doesn't work, as I thought it should. This is the code:

```
<svg fill="none" stroke="#f00" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" 
    width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M16 3.4a9.7 8.3 0 1 0-9.3 14.4"/>
    <ellipse cx="12.2" cy="11" rx="9.7" ry="8.3" stroke="green" opacity=".5"/>
</svg>
```

The picture:

[image]

The red path should follow the green path.

According to the arc code `a rx ry x-axis-rotation large-arc-flag sweep-flag dx dy` it should correspond to the part of ellipse that can be drawn to satisfy the constrains, as the start and the end points and the two radii. As you can see, through the point A and point B passes a green ellipse with radii `9.7` and `8.3`. Why the arc with the same radii and same points doesn't correspond to it?

Can you find what should be the points A and B and radii, so that the acr is exactly the same as the part of the green ellipse?

Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eRXWLq

This is the closest I could get with completely different radii: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EXMXNN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your are using a "sweep flag" set to 0 (anticlockwise), and a "large arc" flag set to 1 (draw the longer of the two ways around the ellipse).  However the anticlockwise distance between the two points on the ellipse is actually the shorter of the two ways around the ellipse.

The solution is to change the "large arc" flag to 0:

```html
<svg fill="none" stroke="#f00" width="400px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" 
    width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M16 3.4a9.7 8.3 0 0 0 -9.3 14.4"/>
    <ellipse cx="12.2" cy="11" rx="9.7" ry="8.3" stroke="green" opacity=".5"/>
</svg>
```

If you are wondering why the arc is still not perfectly accurate, it'll be either:

1. Your start and end points are not accurate. I.e. not perfectly on the ellipse, or
2. Numerical inaccuracy. See this answer for more info: [How to render a svg circle using start and endAngle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45094884/how-to-render-a-svg-circle-using-start-and-endangle/45100420#4510042)